# Unpack function to variables if output is not false

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, function, unpack

Is there a more elegant way to check if function output is not false?
If not, is the second method good solution if function is costly?

```
def get_first_last_name(name):
    if ' ' not in name:
        return False

    return name.split()

if get_first_last_name('John Smith'):
    first_name, last_name = get_first_last_name('John Smith')

output = get_first_last_name('John Smith')
if output:
    first_name, last_name = output
```

Comment: `get_first_last_name` is confusing in that it returns a bool in one case. Why not move the logic for `' ' not in name` outside the function so the function *actually* gets first and last name and nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for reply!
The function I'm working on has 3 steps of check. To go through checks I need to collect some data which also will used to get final output

Answer (score 1):

The major problem with the first solution is that the function runs twice. In this case, this is a waste of CPU time but not much else. If that function carried out side effects though (writing to file, printing to screen), those effects would happen twice. For these reasons, I would completely avoid the first method in really any case.

The second method is pretty typical. That is definitely what I'd go with in a case like this, and is indeed something that I've used many times before.